# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null" , i am using xml based security configuration in spring mvc

Tags: spring

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:289)
org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:237)
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:76)
org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:147)
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.89

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.7.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd%22%3E)

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <form-login  login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginerror" default-target-url="/homelogin" username-parameter="name" password-parameter="password"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"   />

    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logOut"
            invalidate-session="true"/>


</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                               users-by-username-query="select username,concat(password) , 1 from  admin where username=?"
                               authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from admin where username=?"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

<beans:import resource="dispatcher-servlet.xml"/>
</beans:beans>